# Javascript this if function caller is object from DOM

Tags: javascript

I have a button with `onclick` method which calls function.

What is not clear to me, why is `this` inside function seen as Object? Isn't this suppose to be object calling method? In this case it is the button?

I pass only one parameter as `this` to the method. And this parameter correctly shows button (named parameter element inside function).

Why is this inside function not showing button inside DOM which called the method?

```js
var test = (function() {
  var test1 = {
    nameT: 'test'
  };

  methodTesting(test1);

  function methodTesting(element) {
    debugger;
  }
  return {
    methodTesting: methodTesting
  }
});
```

```html
<button onclick="test.methodTesting(this);" data-itest=1 data-ctest2='miran' data-ct='feri'>TEst</button>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Impossible to know what are you asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a reference to the element because you're [assigning it via the `onclick` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler).

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead or get a reference to the element via the [`currentTarget` property of the Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Comment: If I understand this correctly onclick is also an object and that object is calling object in this case?